# OKx V5 Error: {"msg":"Invalid Sign","code":"50113"}

Tags: python

Does anyone know what is missing from my Python code to access the OKx exchange to get my balances from my account to use in my Google Sheets app. I keep getting the Error:

> {"msg":"Invalid Sign","code":"50113"}.

Server Time (UTC-8): 2023-06-07T04:32:23.898Z

Local Time (UTC+2): 2023-06-07T06:32:23.778Z

Adjusted Local Time (UTC+2): 2023-06-07T04:32:23.898Z

The Adjusted local time matches the server time within 30 seconds and I have double checked my `api_key`, `api_secret`, `passphrase` is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
import pytz
import json
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import gspread
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from config import api_key, api_secret, passphrase


# OKEx API base URL
base_url = 'https://www.okex.com'

# Fetch server time
server_time_url = f'{base_url}/api/v5/public/time'
response = requests.get(server_time_url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print("Error retrieving server time:", response.text)
    exit()

# Extract server time from the response
server_time_utc = response.json()['data'][0]['ts']

# Convert server time to floating timestamp format
server_time_float = int(server_time_utc)

# Specify the time zone for the local time
local_timezone = pytz.timezone("Africa/Johannesburg")

# Get the current time in the local time zone
local_time = datetime.now(local_timezone)

# Convert local time to floating timestamp format
local_time_float = int(local_time.timestamp() * 1000)

# Adjust the local time to match the server time
adjusted_local_time_float = local_time_float - (local_time_float - server_time_float)

# Convert the adjusted local time back to datetime object
adjusted_local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(adjusted_local_time_float / 1000, tz=timezone.utc)

# Get the current UTC time
current_utc_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

# Convert the server time to a datetime object
server_time_int = int(response.json()['data'][0]['ts'])
server_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(server_time_int / 1000, tz=timezone.utc)


# Calculate the time difference between the server time and local time
time_difference = current_utc_time - server_time

# Print the time difference
print("Time Difference:", time_difference)

# Convert server time to ISO format
server_time_iso = adjusted_local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3] + "Z"
print("Server Time (UTC-8):", server_time_iso)

# Convert local time to ISO format
local_time_iso = local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3] + "Z"
print("Local Time:", local_time_iso)

# Convert adjusted local time to ISO format
adjusted_local_time_iso = adjusted_local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3] + "Z"
print("Adjusted Local Time:", adjusted_local_time_iso)

# Use the adjusted_local_time_str to create the request payload and signature
request_body = {
    "currency": ""
}


payload_str = json.dumps(request_body, separators=(",", ":"))
timestamp = adjusted_local_time_iso
# prehash_string = timestamp + 'GET' + '/api/v5/account/balance' + payload_str
prehash_string = timestamp + 'GET' + '/api/v5/account/balance'
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), prehash_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
print("Prehash String:", prehash_string)

# Prepare the request headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'OK-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
    'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
    'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,  # Use the timestamp as a string
    'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphrase
}

# Specify the API endpoint URL
url = urljoin(base_url, '/api/v5/account/balance')

# Initialize balances as an empty list
balances = []

# Send the request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=request_body)

# Handle the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    if 'data' in data:
        balances = data['data']
        print("Balances:")
        for balance in balances:
            currency = balance.get('currency')
            available = balance.get('available')
            print(f"Currency: {currency}, Available: {available}")

        # Replace with your credentials file name
        credentials_file = 'credentials.json'

        # Authenticate and access the spreadsheet
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentials_file, scope)
        client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        # Replace with your actual spreadsheet name and sheet name
        googlesheet_name = 'Trading_Data_App'
        sheet_name = 'OKEx_Balances'

        # Open the spreadsheet and select the desired sheet
        spreadsheet = client.open(googlesheet_name)
        sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheet_name)

        # Replace with the cell where you want to place the balances
        cell = 'A2'

        # Update the cell with the balances
        sheet.update(cell, json.dumps(balances))

        print("Balances updated successfully.")
    else:
        print("No balances found in the response.")
else:
    print("Error:", response.text)
```

Comment: it looks like they offer a python library that will take care of auth for you ...

Comment: I still seem to get the same 'invalid sign' error with the python library for some reason...